# Java Timer functionality without inner class

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have below timer functionality implemented in my code

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Timer started");
                //my Logic
            };
        };
        timer.schedule(tt, 60000, 60000);
```

The above timer runs for every 1 minute.
I don't have any issue executing this code.

Since this piece of code has inner class and it also kind of overrides run method
I want to know is there any other efficient way of writing timer logic or is this the only way we can handle timer.

Comment: Why is it that you don’t want an inner class?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You asked for:

> Java Timer functionality without inner class

Define your task as a separate class implementing `Runnable` interface, with an instance submitted to a `ScheduledExecutorService` object.

You get repeated executions with no inner class involved.

## Use executor service

As noted in [their Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html), the `Timer`/`TimerTask` classes have been supplanted by the executors framework added to Java 5. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Obtain an executor service object from the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. To schedule a repeating task, obtain a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

## Define separate class implementing `Runnable`

Submit your task to be executed as an object of type [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html). This interface requires a method `run` which as called by the executor service.

```java
public class TellTime implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println( "Now is " + Instant.now() ) ;
    }
}
```

Instantiate.

```
Runnable task = new TellTime() ;
```

Pass to your executor service. Additional arguments specify how long to wait until first run, and then how often after that to execute repeatedly.

```
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0 , 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

Be sure to eventually shut down your executor service. Otherwise it’s backing thread pool may continue indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can simplify the code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
..

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(() -> doSomething(), 60000);
```

Comment: It still has the inner class. Only a more convenient way of writing it.

Comment: @OleV.V. If you just don't want an inner class you can just extend class `TimerTask` as separate class and then use it

Comment: As [noted in the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html), the `Timer`/`TimerTask` classes have been supplanted by the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).